# Finding $n$, $n^n \equiv k \pmod m$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

What is the general process of finding $n$ such that
$$n^n \equiv k \pmod m?$$

---

I tried working with an example, say $k=60$ and $m=120.$ Then, I know that $2,3,5 \mid n.$ So, Letting $n=30w,$ We have
$$30w^{30w} \equiv 30^{30w}(w)^{30w}$$
But continuing this thought leaves me an expression with $w^w$ again. The problem I feel is that the exponent of $n^n$ is varying, so I can't really deduce many properties about it.

Comment: there might not always be an n

Comment: Note that in your example $n^n=(30w)^{30w}=(30^{30})^ww^{30w}$, where $120\mid30^{30}$, so if $w>0$ then $n^n\equiv0\pmod{120}$. This shows there is no $n$ such that $n^n\equiv60\pmod{120}$.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the comments, a solution does not always necessarily exist. However, we can always find a solution in the case of a prime modulus. I am copying my solution from [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3733057/if-p-is-a-prime-and-a-%E2%88%88z-how-do-we-prove-that-the-congruence-xx-%E2%89%A1-a-mod-p-is/3733079) here because that topic has been closed and the solution might not survive deletion of the thread:

> Assume WLOG that $0\le a<p.$ If $p\mid a$ then we can choose $x=p.$ If $p\nmid a,$ then Fermat's little theorem says that $$a^{p-1} \equiv 1\pmod p.$$ Also, $$a^p \equiv a\pmod p.$$ Then for any integers $m,n,$
> $$(a+pn)^{p+m(p-1)}\equiv a\pmod p.$$ So we just need to find integers $m,n$ such that $$a+pn=p+m(p-1).$$ This is equivalent to $$pn-(p-1)m=p-a.$$ Since $$p\cdot 1 + (p-1)\cdot (-1)=1,$$ we can let $n=p-a$ and $m=p-a.$ Indeed, this works because the base $a+p(p-a)$ is equal to the exponent $p+(p-a)(p-1).$ This can be checked by expansion.

Of course, this only constructs a solution and does not find all solutions. If you want a challenge, find infinitely many solutions using this line of reasoning and the classification of all solutions to a two-variable linear Diophantine equation.